# Show <apex:pageMessages> in javascript

Tags: javascript, salesforce

How to show apex:pageMessages in javascript? Here is my code in vf page

```
<apex:form id="frm">
                            <apex:pageBlock id="pb1">
                            <div style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 50px;">
                            <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>
                            </div>
       </apex:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an [apex:actionFunction](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) and controller method to add the error message and rerender the pageMessages.

**Page:**

```
<apex:pageBlock id="messages">
    <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg" />
</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:actionFunction name="showPageMessage" action="{!showPageMessage}" rerender="messages">
  <apex:param name="level" assignTo="{!level}" value="" />
  <apex:param name="message" assignTo="{!message}" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>
<!--...-->
<script>
  showMessage('WARNING', 'Here is the page message');
<script>
```

**Controller**

```
//...
public String level {get; set;}
public String message {get; set;}

public void showPageMessage() {
  if(level == 'WARNING') {
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning, message));
  }
}
```